# angular and turning json data into real objects (and vice-versa)

Tags: json, angular, ngrx, class-transformer

To keep this simple:

I have classes defined in typescript which have methods and properties (with lots of getter/setter logic). I then retrieve json data matching such classes. I need to be able to project these json objects into my "smart" classes. I know about [class transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) but I wonder if this is really go-to approach to do this kind of stuff. Furthermore, I'm planning on using ngrx, so this whole class-transformation just looks wrong (server to json, json to state, state to class? and viceversa? I just dont see a clear pattern.

Any clarity is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing almost exactly what you describe in a fairly large app.
I'm using class-transformer to transform the JSON from http calls to instances of the appropriate objects, and then using the resulting objects as state in a store (except that I'm using Redux instead of ngrx).

I find that it works very well.

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "server to json, json to state, state to class? and viceversa?".

For me (using your terminology), it's server to json, json to class, class to state
(but state is just a collection of objects, i.e. class instances. I.E. state *is* objects).

If I need to send state back to the server, then yes, I typically pull the appropriate objects from the store, serialize them to JSON, and send them to the server. But...the Angular HttpClient does the serialization for you, so you don't typically have to write that part, unless you need some custom serialization.

Comment: Hi! I'm marking this as answer just because you took the time to answer and also because you say this im trying to do works for you. But I have a few questions. 1. if you go "json to class"  before setting it as state, arent you risking mutating your state outside of the redux control? Properties will change other properties and such? 2. Do you use any library for json-to-class? 3. I'm going to give this a shot (still lots to do before actually trying it) .... woudl you mind if I contact you by private message in case I reach some dead end? thanks mate

Comment: what i mean by state-to-class is that i read somewere that redux doesnt like 'smart' objects so I assumed one would have to instantiate the "real" class (the one with property setters) just after selecting it from the store. If you use such classes in your store then I feel more confident to do so as well. But you see my point?

Comment: 1. No. Don't know what you are imagining will happen. If you're really worried about it, I suppose that you could have a reducer do the conversion. I wouldn't store JSON in the store, if that's what you're asking.

2. Yes, as I mentioned, I'm using class-transformer. Feel free to PM me.

If by "smart objects", you mean ones with methods that change the object's state, then yes, you might want to make those state changes in the reducers instead. I typically don't store "smart" objects, but I do store objects with properties that are not strings, dates, and numbers, so need deserialization.

Comment: by smart i mean objects whose properties (setters) migth hold logic like a property birthdate that updates the "age" property when set. There could be methods as well like "calculateAgeFromBidthdate()". So I do not care about the structural complexity of the object but for the business logic it might hold